Woman hit by a carriage
I recall some details from a movie I'd like to identify:
Older female whose father was an protester in Europe and whose leg was hit by a horse wagon during a protest. The accident caused her to be in pain for much of her life.
I think the woman was an older relative of the main character, the father was an anarchist and the characters where Jewish.

Approximate year? Was it in English? And by the tags, I take it this could be a TV show\miniseries?

I thought it might be the movie Avalon (1990) or the Sopranos, but I searched everywhere and couldn't find any reference.

It's Lost in Yonkers (1993).

When she was 12 years old...
...her old man takes her to a political rally in Berlin.
The cops break it up with sticks, on horseback.
Somebody throws a rock, and a cop bashes in her old man's head.
And then a horse goes down and crushes Ma's foot...
...and nobody ever fixed it.
Hurts every single day of her life. I never once seen her take even an
  aspirin.
That's moxie, kid.

